# UIPickerView 2nd component populates blank the second time the picker view is shown

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView with 2 components. Selecting 1st components populates 2nd component. Looks like this:

[image]

Test Case:

1. Select any option in `Component 0` and then pick any episode in `Component 1` of picker and click `Fitler` which hides the picker.
2. Show the Picker again to select something else. The first component loads properly. The second component is blank like this screenshot:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{
    UILabel* tView = (UILabel*)view;
    if (!tView){
        tView = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        tView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        // Setup label properties - frame, font, colors etc
        //...
        //adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth property to YES

        if(pickerView == self.seasonEpiPickerView && component == 1){
            tView.font= [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
            tView.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        }
    }

    // Fill the label text here
     if (pickerView == self.seasonEpiPickerView)
    {
        if (component == 0) {
            if (row == 0) {
                item = @"All";
            } else {
                //NSLog(@"c1:%ld", (long)row);
                item = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%@", ((Season *)[self.media.seasonManager.seasonArray objectAtIndex:row-1]).seasonNr];
            }

        } else if (component == 1){
            if(self.media.seasonManager && self.media.seasonManager.seasonArray && [self.media.seasonManager.seasonArray count]>0 ) {
                Season* tempSeason = self.media.seasonManager.seasonArray[[self.seasonEpiPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]-1];
                item = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@ \"%@\"", tempSeason.seasonNr, [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%02d", [((Episode *)[tempSeason.episodeManager.episodeArray objectAtIndex:row]).episodeNr intValue]], ((Episode *)[tempSeason.episodeManager.episodeArray objectAtIndex:row]).title];
                NSLog(@"c2:%ld:%@", (long)row, item);
            }
        }
    }
    tView.text = item;

    return tView;
}
```

**Edit:**

Here's how I create the Picker in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.seasonPickerViewTextField  = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[self.view addSubview:self.seasonPickerViewTextField];

self.seasonEpiPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
self.seasonEpiPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
self.seasonEpiPickerView.dataSource = self;
self.seasonEpiPickerView.delegate = self;

//add the toolbar for the season picker
UIToolbar *toolBar= [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,screenWidth,44)];
[toolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonDone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Filter   " style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(filterByEpisode:)];
UIBarButtonItem *flexible = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *barCancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"   Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(cancelPicker:)];
toolBar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: barCancelButton, flexible, barButtonDone, nil];
self.seasonPickerViewTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;

// set change the inputView (default is keyboard) to UIPickerView
self.seasonPickerViewTextField.inputView = self.seasonEpiPickerView;
```

**EDIT 2**
doing a delayed reload when the picker view is presented the second time reloads the second component correctly. This seems very hawkish.

```
- (IBAction)pickEpisodeButton:(id)sender
{
    [self.seasonPickerViewTextField becomeFirstResponder];

    /* None of the following commented lines of code have any effect*/
    //[self.seasonEpiPickerView selectRow:1 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
    //[self.seasonEpiPickerView selectRow:selectedSeason inComponent:0 animated:YES];
    //[self.seasonEpiPickerView selectRow:selectedEpisode inComponent:1 animated:YES];
    //[self.seasonEpiPickerView reloadComponent:1];

    //set a 1.5 sec timer to go to the next screen
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1f target:self selector:@selector(loadSecondComponent) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}


-(void)loadSecondComponent {
    [self.seasonEpiPickerView reloadComponent:1];
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "when I go back to the picker view"?

Comment: It means: When I want to select another item from the picker view.

Comment: Still not clear. What exact steps lead to the 2nd component being blank? Do you simply mean that if you pick a value in the 1st component, you see the expected values in the 2nd. But if you then pick a different value in the 1st component, the 2nd is now blank?

Comment: If you pick a value in the 1st component, you see the expected values in the 2nd. When you open the picker view again, the 1st component is displayed with the previously selected value, but the 2nd component is blank. The 2nd component should also be displayed with the previously selected value. I hope this explains it.

Comment: When you first load the picker view and set the initial value for the 1st component, you need to add code to populate the 2nd component based on the 1st component.

Comment: Please check the edit. What changes can I make to populate the 2nd component based on the 1st?

Comment: Where's the code that does the initial setup of the picker view and sets the initial value in the 1st component?

Comment: I am just showing the same picker again and don't pre-select the index anywhere. I also notice that when the second component is blank and i just tap the first component (same already selected index) then the second component populates properly.